# How to modify a specific line of function in R package (RTextTools)?

Tags: r, trace

I am using a package from R and it has a bug, but I don't know how to fix this permanently.

By using trace(), I can fix this every run, but I need to fix this permanently.

p.s. it's just a typo, so I just need to change a letter ("A" to "a") and I know which line I should modify.

Another way that I was trying is to replace the original function file with the updated function file. I do have a fixed function (XXX.r), but I don't have a new package to install. I tried to find where the original function code was, but it seems like it's not visible as far as I understand. ( I might be missing something ).

Any helps would be appreciated.

Comment: If the function is only called by you, then just save the source of the function, change it, and source it after `library(RTextTools)`. If you the function is used by other functions within the package, well, it might be feasible to alter its loaded namespace, but I think you're better off just cloning the entire package source, changing the function, up-ing the version slightly, and build/install it locally.

Comment: If it's really a bug, you should report it to the package author(s) so that they can fix it. If the package is on GitHub you may file an "issue" or a "pull request".